# Renaming BLE Device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Why doesn't the Generic attribute and generic access `GAP UUID x1800` service show up when trying to discover for services on iOS? It shows up in Android.

How do people go on about changing a BLE device name in iOS devices? Do they just create a separate service with a device characteristic that changes the device name?

Comment: How did you try to find it? You should be able to find it. Device renaming is up to the device. Some offers the possibility to change the name, others done.

Comment: @Larme once i connect I try to scan for services. On Android I can see the services, but on iOS I can.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?